# Words choice , describe how essay starts from broad idea and narrowed down

Tags: word-choice

I want to describe how essay starts from broad idea and narrowed down in one one/two word(s) something like evolution of essay

Thanks

Comment: deduced? as in following deductive reasoning? ideas are streamlines? themes are developed? refinement?

Comment: I think this is Not Constructive, or Off Topic (belongs on writers.se). Apart from anything else, essays/theses/dissertations/etc. don't normally start with broad ideas which are then narrowed down to one or two words. Perhaps OP might find some advice [here](http://www.fas.harvard.edu/~wricntr/documents/Structure.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my own writing, using titled sections, I would start with the *Introduction*, *Background*, and *Overview*. Any of those section titles (or all, depending on how complex your topic is) can be used to advise the reader on how to become acquainted with the topic without immediately jumping into the details. They provide a useful place to show how the details evolve from something less complex and/or more familiar to your readers.

You might think that *Abstract* or *Summary* would also be appropriate section titles, but the words don't quite capture what you are looking for, in my view.